# Why is the following Javascript code not working?

Tags: javascript

```
function user(){
user.name ="Amine";
user.lastName ='Meziane';
document.write(user.name);
};
user();
```

When executing it writes "user" only and not the name "Amine"

Comment: Did you not see the placeholder text when you entered your question. Specifically "Be specific". How do you ask a good question? Simple... [follow the help guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I said it's not working I'm looking for the solution it's not something that creates debates.  thank you for your comment

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function() {
function user(){
var json = '{"name":"Amine","lastName":"Meziane"}',
    obj = JSON.parse(json);
    document.body.innerHTML=obj.name+' '+obj.lastName;
}
user();
};
//or
function user(){
   var user = {};
   user.name ="Amine";
   user.lastName ='Meziane';
   document.write(user.name);
};
user();
```

Comment: Why use JSON? It seems completely superfluous; you could have used an object literal.

Comment: that's the point. I don't know which is Json and which is Pure Java. Libraries are getting me crazy lool !!! can you help me plz..  thank you

Comment: this is Json and I'm trying to learn pure Java. maybe I wrote an anti-pattern no?

Comment: JSON is Javascript, it is actually the object literal syntax with some restrictions. You pass the JSON through a parser, so you are sure the JSON Data isn't harmfull. But you could also just do 'jsonObject = eval(JSON)'.

Comment: Please don't shorten Javascript, with Java. Thats an TOTALLY different language.

Comment: jason: for simple understanding becomes more variable javascript

Comment: is an exclusive sheet to define text, and it is actually javascript

Comment: ya know and I started to learn Java basics before JavaScript's ones

Answer (score 4):

`user` refers to the `user` function, which comes with an existing, unassignable `name` property initialized to the function name. The `user.name ="Amine";` assignment is ignored.

Comment: Yep, OP probably wants `new user()` and `this.name = …`.

Comment: @Kay Or `function user() { var user = {}; ... }`.

Comment: but in the beginning of the JavaScript courses they say that every thing are considered as object no? so function and variables and classes are objects?  thank you for commenting.

Comment: Functions are objects, but the name property of such an object isn't modifyable. Variables are alias/names referencing objects. Classes don't exist in javascript. It's a prototype based language. The Objects could be cloned. They are actually only key-value stores. A value can be an function/objects/(primitiv value).

Comment: ok got it know but when I run it I writes the function name "user" why is that hapenning. according to someone commented in here "function's names are their values too". so if I would name my function "worldSoccer" It would write its name "worldSoccer"  no?

Comment: @user3099032: If you had named your function `worldSoccer`, it would have written `worldSoccer`.

Answer (score 1):

As user2357112 pointed out, your Code tries to modify the name property of the function `user`. This property isn't modifieable. And so it doesn't change. The name property of the function `user`, contains the name of the function `user`, which is `"user"` :-). And this name is what your code prints out.

You can write:

```
function user(){
   var user = {};
   user.name = "Amine";
   user.lastName = "Meziane";
   document.write(user.name);
};
user();
```

Here `user`(`.name`) will not refer to the function `user`, but to the local variable (`var`) `user`, which is initialized with an object literal (`{}`).

Maybe you wanted to write an constructor function. Then you would add properties to `this`.

```
function User(name, lastname){
  this.name = name;
  this.lastName = lastname;
  return this; //optional
};

var userAmine = new User("Amine", "Meziane"); // don't forget "new"
document.write(userAmine.name);
```

Maybe you can read [JavaScript Patterns by Stoyan Stefanov](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596806767.do) for deeper understanding of JavaScript.

Comment: same with Java than but her is a function.. good thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Because the name of the function is read-only. Refer to documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name